# Prawn generating PDF on localhost but not on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, pdf-generation, prawn

I am working on an Ruby on Rails application which uses prawn to generate PDF's when a user clicks on a link. The functionality works when running the application on the localhost but when i deploy it to the server and click on the link the file doesnt load with the message "Failed to load PDF document".

I have done some research and seen references in other places regarding other documents generating gems but none specific to Prawn. Any requests for additional information will gladly be met.

I think showing the code might help so here goes. It is financial application where a page lists statements with a view button and a pdf icon to view them pdf format. When the user clicks on the pdf icon prawn then comes into play. Hope this help clarify my problem somewhat.

Controller Code:

```
    require 'json'

InternetBanking.controllers :statements do
  get :index do
    @today = Time.now
    render 'statements/listing'
  end

  get :listing do
    @today = Time.now
    render 'statements/listing'
  end

  get :activity, provides: [:json] do
    content_type :json
    @customer.accounts.map{|x| {x.name => x.activity}}.to_json
  end

  get :show, map: "/statements/:id", provides: [:html, :pdf] do
    begin
      m = params[:id].force_encoding('UTF-8').match(/(\d+)-(\w+)-(\d+)/)
      accountno = m[1].to_i
      month     = Date::MONTHNAMES.index(m[2])
      year      = m[3].to_i

      raise Exception if month.nil? or year.nil?

      # Fetch account_id from logged in customer, prevent crafted URLs.
      @account = @customer.fetch_account(accountno)

      raise Exception if @account.nil?

      @statement = @account.statement(year, month)

      # TODO: Deal with no transactions
      if content_type == :pdf
        content_type 'application/pdf'
        @statement.to_pdf
      else # HTML
        render 'statements/show'
      end
      rescue
        flash[:error]= 'You cannot have an empty month field'
    end
  end
end
```

Model Code:

Statement.rb

```
class Statement 
  attr_accessor :opening_balance, :closing_balance 

  def initialize(acct, year = nil, month = nil)
    @db = Database.instance
    @account    = acct
    @year       = year
    @month      = month
    @month_name = Date::MONTHNAMES[@month]
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@account.number}-#{@month_name}-#{@year}"
  end

  def to_pdf
    title = @account.name
    subtitle = "Account Statement: #{@month_name} #{@year}"
    StatementPDF.new(title, subtitle, transactions).render
  end

  def transactions
    return @transactions if @transactions


    start  = Date.civil(@year, @month).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    finish = Date.civil(@year, @month, -1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


    rows = @db.call('IBStatement2', @account.account_id, start, finish)
    @transactions = rows.map {|txn| Transaction.new(txn)}
  end
end
```

Statement_pdf.rb

```
require 'prawn'

class StatementPDF < Prawn::Document
  BOX_MARGIN   = 36
  # Additional indentation to keep the line measure with a reasonable size
  INNER_MARGIN = 30
  # Vertical Rhythm settings
  RHYTHM  = 10
  LEADING = 2
  # Colors
  BLACK      = "000000"
  LIGHT_GRAY = "F2F2F2"
  GRAY       = "DDDDDD"
  DARK_GRAY  = "333333"
  BROWN      = "A4441C"
  ORANGE     = "F28157"
  LIGHT_GOLD = "FBFBBE"
  DARK_GOLD  = "EBE389"
  BLUE       = "0000D0"
  GREY       = "CCCCCC"

  def initialize(title, subtitle, rows)
    @rows = rows
    @title = title
    @subtitle = subtitle

    super(page_size: 'A4') do
      define_grid(columns: 4, rows: 16, gutter: 10)

      header

      transactions_table

      footer
    end
  end

  private

  def header 
    grid([0,0],[1,0]).bounding_box do
      image 'public/images/Statement/logo.png', width: 110
    end

    grid([0,1],[1,1]).bounding_box do
      font_size 10
      text 'Yada', font_weight: 'bold'
      font_size 9
      text 'Yada'
      text 'Yada'
      text 'Yada'
      text 'Yada'
      text 'Yada'
      text 'Yada'
    end

    grid([0,2],[0,3]).bounding_box do
      font_size(20)
      text @title, color: '#0044AA', :align => :right
      font_size(14)
      text @subtitle, color: '#0044AA', :align => :right, :valign => :bottom
    end

    font_size(12)
  end 

  def footer
    grid([15,0],[15,3]).bounding_box do
      image 'public/images/statement-logo.png', width: 100
    end
  end

  def transactions_table
    grid([2,0], [13,3]).bounding_box do
      data = [%w(Date Description Amount Balance)]
      data += @rows.map{|r| [r.value_date, r.description, r.amount, r.balance]}
      options = { header: true, width: 520, 
          column_widths: {0 => 100, 2 => 100},
          row_colors: ['EEEEEE', 'FFFFFF']}
      table(data, options) do 
        cells.padding      = 5
        cells.border_width = 0.5
        cells.border_color = GREY

        row(0).font_weight = 'bold'
        row(0).border_color = BLACK
        row(1).border_top_color = BLACK

        column(2).align = :right
        column(3).align = :right
      end
    end
  end
end
```

View Code:

```
- content_for :title, 'Full Statement Listing'

- content_for :toolbar do
  %a.back(href='/balances') Back

%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th.year(rowspan=2) Year
      %th.month(rowspan=2) Month
      %th.accounts{colspan: @customer.accounts.size} Accounts
    %tr
      - @customer.accounts.each do |account|
        %th= account.name
  - @today.year.downto(@today.year - 3) do |year|
    %tbody
      - x = (@today.year == year) ? @today.month : 12
      - x.downto(1) do |month|
        %tr
          - if month == x
            %td{rowspan: x}= year
          %td= Date::MONTHNAMES[month]
          - @customer.accounts.each do |acct|
            - if acct.activity[year] && acct.activity[year][month]
              %td{'data-transactions' => acct.activity[year][month]}
                - stmt = acct.statement(year, month)
                = link_to 'View', url(:statements, :show, id: stmt.to_s)
                = link_to image_tag('/icons/document-pdf.png', alt: 'Download PDF'), url(:statements, :show, id: stmt, format: :pdf), class: :pdf
            - else
              %td
```

Comment: What kind of server is it?  Heroku?  VPS?  Dedicated? Something else?

Comment: Have you tried watching your server log as you try to generate the PDF?  That should always be your first step.

Comment: Apologies. Its an apache tomcat server. I will try to locate the server logs and get back to you. Has anyone ever had this occur before.

Comment: Apologies but trying to locate server log and have been directed on other pages to catalina_out but there is no mention of pdf generation but more higher end tasks.

Comment: If the log doesn't give you any useful feedback (which is surprising, i'd expect to see an exception or error message) I would look at the controller or model code that actually makes the pdf, and step through it in the rails console, on your server.

Comment: Is your server a shared server?  (ie virtual server on a box where you and other users each have a virtual server)  If so then these often block certain processes to stop one user hogging resources.

Comment: Are you actually generating a file?  Or are you using something like `send_data`.  If you're generating a file the app might have permission to write to wherever you're writing.

Comment: The catalina.out log seems to only reference war builds and deploys etc. I tried again this morning, took a note of the time and checked the logs for any change but nothing.

Comment: I'm on digital ocean but i'm not sure if we have a shared server but dont think we do.

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm doing a send_data but there doesnt seem to be any reference to it in the code.

Comment: UPDATE


I have been working on another pdf and noticed a difference with path name. When testing it locally it works and i've noticed the path is 'public/images/logo.png' whereas when live it should be 'images/logo.png' so i believe that is the issue. Redeploying now to see if it has an effect. On another note is there a way to have a variable that specifies path based on what environment the application is being deployed in.